# Stored procedure not found

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have this code for inserting data into database using Windows forms application.

But I get this error

> Could not find stored procedure 'sp_insert'

I am not using any external server and it's a Local db

UPDATE: it seemed that I don't have a stored procedure so I tried to create one but it throws another error

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insert
    @UserName varchar(20),
    @Password varchar(18),
    @Email varchar(50),
    @Name varchar(20),
    @Surname varchar(20)
AS
    -- here the error occurs "error near syntax" but User is my table name 
    -- and it's  correct I don't know what is the problem is
    INSERT INTO User (UserName, Password, Email, Name, Surname)
    VALUES (@UserName, @Password, @Email, @Name, @Surname)
```

C# code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=    (LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\TaxiBooking\TaxiBooking\TaxiBooking\Registraion.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_insert", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName",txtUser.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", txtSurname.Text);

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: The error seems pretty obvious, don't you think? Do you have a stored procedure with that name in that database? As a side note, naming stored procedure with the sp_ prefix is considered wrong because you can get in conflit with system stored procedure names

Comment: @Steve Oops i figured it out after i posted the question. now i tried to add a stored procedure but it shows an error

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: You should show us the full error msg otherwise, we are not able to help.
Include the exact procedure code would be even better since the problem might have something to do with it and I wonder if it's exactly like what you typed in the code block.

Comment: "user" is a keyword, change the name of the table. Until you do, you can use  [user].

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @JBrooks Sorry I plagiarised - I didn't see your comment, but note it as an earlier answer than mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a reserved word:

Change

```
 INSERT INTO User( UserName,Password,Email,Name,Surname)
```

to

```
 INSERT INTO [User]( UserName,Password,Email,Name,Surname)
```

Try to avoid the use of terms that look like they will be shared with the OS or application you are coding against.  You will save yourself some headaches.

Answer (score 2):

why don't you try dbo.sp_insert.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.sp_insert", con);
```